# Remaining time until due time

Tags: grammar

Which one is right:
1-there is much time until due date
2-there is long time until due date
3-Much time is left until due date

Comment: You need a "none of the above" choice.  If you are trying to say the due date is relatively far in the future, "Much time remains before the due date".

Comment: *Much time remains until the due date* is also possible.

Comment: "Much time" sounds odd to me as a UK person, maybe it's better in other versions of English. I'd prefer "A lot of time", "a long time", etc.

Answer (score 0):

> There is much time until due date.

> There is long time until due date.

> Much time is left until due date

Well, these are all wrong, because we need to add "the." However, the question is surely asking about the other part of the sentence, because they all lack "the." Let's also fix the missing "a" in "there is **a** long time." Let's fix it and try again:

> There is much time until the due date.

Hm. Technically correct, but not natural sounding. One might say this as a joke, perhaps impersonating a British person.

> There is [a] long time until the due date.

With the addition of "a," this is correct. Without "a," it is incorrect. With "a," it is clearly the best option out of the three.

> Much time is left until the due date

This is okay, and it is not incorrect. However, "there's lots of time before the due date" is better.

In general on 2. and 3., if you want to sound more natural, try using "before" instead of "until."